# Is there any way to change the month dropdown on react-datepicker to show number instead of the name itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-datepicker

So I have here

```
 <DatePicker
   selected={value?.toDate()}
   onChange={(date) => this.handleMonthChange(date)}
   inline
   showMonthYearPicker
   dateFormat={this.props.formatString}
   />
```

[image]

I want to achieve that instead of Jan. It will display 01, and so on for other months. Thank you

Comment: You're probably looking for this https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-month

Comment: Actually, I'm using it now, adding showMonthYearPicker on Datepicker, but want I want to achieve is the dropdown menu will show numbers instead of Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc...

Comment: Ooh, sorry, I didn't see that part. My bad for not double-checking. Now I get it. Thanks, mate! such a help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define a `renderMonthContent` method and pass it as a prop to your `DatePicker`.

As the `month` variable is the month's index (and as such, January is 0 instead of 1) we increment by 1.

Also, we add `.toString().padStart(2, 0)` to achieve the always-2-digit presentation you want.

```js
const Component = () => {
  const renderMonthContent = (month, shortMonth, longMonth) => {
    return <span>{(month+1).toString().padStart(2, 0)}</span>;
  };
  ...

  return (
    <DatePicker
       selected={value?.toDate()}
       onChange={(date) => this.handleMonthChange(date)}
       inline
       showMonthYearPicker
       dateFormat={this.props.formatString}
       renderMonthContent={renderMonthContent}
       />
    ...
  );
};
```

Results:

[image: datepicker example]

Comment: It's a good idea to lift `renderMonthContent` out of `Component` if it does not depend on any states/props/hooks. Currently `renderMonthContent` is re-defined every time `Component` renders, which doesn't seem necessary. Other than that, good answer.

Comment: @3limin4t0r is right on that. I didn't consider it while answering.